# Streaming Infopath form data from web server - strange behaviour in Fiddler trace

Tags: infopath, fiddler

I have a simple aspx page that streams Infopath form data to the client. That then opens in the Infopath template on the client machine. Works fine.

However when I look at the Fiddler trace I see 7 calls to my aspx page - the original one from the browser, then several times more from the Infopath process. My form data ends up being downloaded 4 times - once by the browser and 3 times by Infopath!

[Here's a link to the Fiddler trace file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17133472/Infopath.saz)
 - if anyone can explain what is going on here I would be grateful.

How does Infopath even know about the aspx file & why does it need to call it at all, leave alone calling it several times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infopath (and actually most MS Office applications) has code which attempts to determine where a given form came from and then use the content from that server rather than a local copy. This is typically important to offer the ability to post updates back to the original source (e.g. a SharePoint site). Generally you shouldn't see multiple *full* downloads, although you certainly may see several HEAD, OPTIONS or other WebDav verbs.

(The Office team is working to reduce redundant downloads but this isn't trivial for a bunch of reasons).